# Cannot create "Analysis Services Multidimentional and Datamining" project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssas, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, I cannot create "Analysis Services Multidimensional and Datamining project" even "Microsoft Analysis Services Projects" extension v2.9.10 is installed and I am able to create "Analysis Services Tabular" project.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In extension tab go to -Manage Extensions- -Installed- -Turn off Analysis services extension-
Reopen Visual studio, turn Analysis services extension on.
Reopen Visual studio.

It worked for me :)